# OneNote's "Personal (Web)" notebook won't sync properly after phone reset

Tags: sync, onedrive, onenote

I recently reset my Windows Phone (a Lumia 820), and it recovered without problems, bar one. When I open OneNote, the "Personal (Web)" notebook appears as open, but "syncing with OneDrive...". If I tap on it, it shows only the Quick Notes section, which is selected as the default note location. No amount of waiting for it to sync shows any other sections.

If I open the OneDrive app and find the notebook there, then tap on it, it opens in OneNote and shows all of the sections as it should, however the Quick Notes section says "syncing" and never goes any further. If I return to the list of notebooks, I now have two copies of "Personal (Web)".

My problems are:

- I can't get to my original Quick Notes
- I can't close the new Personal (Web) notebook because it contains the default note section
- I can't change the default note section to another because the current note section is still syncing
- The continuous syncing seems to be sucking up my mobile data, which is a pain

I've tried resetting Office from Settings/Applications, but I just find myself back in the same position.

My only other thought at this point is, should I rename my original Personal (Web) notebook in OneDrive, or will that cause me more problems?

UPDATE:

After resetting Office yet again, I tried disconnecting the phone from all data connections. I still had two copies of "Personal (Web)", but neither were syncing, which allowed me to change the default note location to a different tab in my original notebook. Once this was done, I could disconnect the default "Personal (Web)" notebook, and things are almost back to normal.

The only problem I'm left with is that my Quick Notes are still syncing, and I can't access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running into the same issues again with an entirely different phone, I found a workaround.

It turns out that the issue was the size of the folders in my main notebook, especially my Quick Notes section. I had used Quick Notes on many occasions to save scanned documents from Office Lens on my phone, and so there was a lot of image data there. I created a new notebook called "Archive" and moved all my old scans there, in the process reducing my Quick Notes to a much more reasonable size. I also moved a lot of my Quick Notes into more relevant folders, something I should have done anyway.

My Quick Notes are now synchronizing properly with my phone and I can once again make that folder my default.